# What API do i use for my Flutter and Firebase app?

Tags: flutter, firebase, rest

I am building a very simple carpooling app for my university using Firebase and flutter. Students will be logging in using their university email, have the option to create a ride or browse available rides. If they create a ride, they can add their car details, gender preferences, origin/destination location (they will be choosing this from a dropdown list, maps wont be integrated) and time. Student can browse available rides by choosing origin and destination location along with added filters (gender preferences, AC/no-AC etc.) and matching rides will be shown. As I need to make an API document, do i use Firebase functions or do I use REST API that interacts with Firebase and Flutter both. I am a complete beginner so any leads would be much appreciated!

Comment: If the simplicity is what you are after, use Firestore: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#dart. No need for functions or separate REST API.

Comment: Thankyou! If i use Firestore, then making an API document won't be required right?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.